# Android - Creating Images and Icons

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on an Android Application which requires some design but i am basically a developer with not much knowledge about designing stuff and i am working on the projects alone. Can anybody please help me about how to go with designing or some good links where i can learn it? Also can you also provide some links which would be a tool where i can create decent icons and images for my android application?

THANK YOU.

Comment: For general design help, why not just look at some of the apps that you use regularly? You'll get a good idea of what kind of interfaces work and don't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i think this url may be useful to you

- [https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=image&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher](http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools)
- http://www.mutualmobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/MM_Android_Design_Guidelines.pdf

Comment: Both the links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

**For getting the icons you have to refer the following:-**

https://www.iconfinder.com/

**And For converting the icons in mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi and .9png you have to look into this:-**

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

hope it helps you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

this might be helpful to you :)

> http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html
>
> http://www.spiderflyapps.com/downloads/android-developer-icons-the-font/
>
> http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/free-icon-sets-10134829
>
> http://www.androiduipatterns.com/
>
> http://www.pixeden.com/media-icons
>
> http://phandroid.com/2011/05/11/10-tips-for-android-ui-design/
>
> http://subtlepatterns.com/
>
> http://androiduiux.com/free-design-resources/
>
> https://speakerd.s3.amazonaws.com/presentations/ca8eeed0b9800130dc6346296d6789e9/Android_UI_Design_Patterns_in_practice_en_droidcon_reduced.pdf